# GKE config connector issue - Post i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running into the below error when creating compute IP.
Config connector is already enabled, and it is a private cluster hosted on a shared network.
Version 1.17.15-gke.800

```
$ kubectl apply -f webapp-compute-ip. yaml
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "webapp-compute-ip.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "annotation-defaulter.cnrm.cloud.google.com": Post https://cnrm-validating-webhook.cnrm-system.svc:443/annotation-defaulter?timeout=30s: dial tcp 192.168.66.130:9443: i/o timeout
```

$cat webapp-compute-ip.yaml

```
apiVersion: compute.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ComputeAddress
metadata:
  name: webapp-ip-test
namespace: sandbox
labels:
    app: webapp
    environment: test
annotations:
cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: "cluster-name"
spec:
  location: global`
```

Comment: is this Kubernetes open source or Google Kubernetes Engine ?
did you enabled [PodSecurityPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies#enabling_podsecuritypolicy_controller) ? does this work on a newly deployed GKE cluster ?

Comment: This is GKE with config connector enabled. PodSecurity is not enabled. I think I have nailed it down now, working on it. will post a detailed answer later.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to a config connector version issue.

There was a change in the webhook default port, from 443 to 9443, [see](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/pull/1076)

Config connector version depends on [GKE version](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall#upgrading), I did not have any control over it, moreover there no is public documentation available on what config connector version is available with the GKE version. There is an existing request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/174305850).

The solution was for me to add port 9443 in the firewall rule.